# variable inside blocktranslate not translated when makemessages

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization

I make a simple template like this

```
<button class="btn">{% blocktranslate %}{{ greeting }} Quy!{% endblocktranslate %}</button>
```

with `greeting` equals `hello`.
I have added the following `MIDDLEWARE`, and `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'vi'`. Everything else is left as default.

```
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
```

and

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "vi"

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('vi', _('Vietnamese')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

After running `django-admin makemessages -l vi`, the `.po` file is created

```
msgid "%(greeting)s Quy!"
msgstr ""
```

I added

```
# vi/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
msgid "hello"
msgstr "chào"
```

or

```
# en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
msgid "hello"
msgstr "hi"
```

and then run `django-admin compilemessages` but "hello" shown up instead of "chào" or "hi". Why I cannot translate the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tries it with tag `translate`, and it works if I send variable `greeting` as "hello", whereas for `blocktranslate` I need `_("hello")`